# Suspending Windows then Starting Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I was wondering if there is a way to "pause" windows 8 then go switch over to Ubuntu.  Occasionally when my laptop dies, it shuts down, but then will boot up without actually starting windows again.  It shows the boot screen, but has my programs already open, and does not take a long time to load.  Last time this happened, I booted up Ubuntu instead of windows, and when I needed to switch back to use windows, it retained the much faster start up speed.  It has the programs open that were there when it ran out of battery.

I have linux on a ssd, but due to windows coming on my laptop, it remains on my hdd.  The boot time for windows is ridiculous, and I was hoping this would allow me to switch between the two more freely.  If it helps I use a Lenovo y580.

So is there a way to pause windows 8, keeping programs open, then use Ubuntu as my os, and then reboot back up windows keeping the programs and faster start time?  Or is that just my laptop doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe hibernation is state you can use. In hibernation mode all OS copies all RAM contents to HDD and totally power off itself. But on boot it copies all contents back to RAM and that process is not so fast (in case you have slow HDD and alot of RAM). You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Power_states)